# Kotlin: Iterate over components of object

Tags: kotlin

Each data class object has a component for each property like component1, component2, etc..
I was wondering if there is any way in Kotlin to iterate over each component of a class.
Say I have class:

```
data class User(age:Int, name:String)
```

Could I do something like:

```
for(component in aUserObject){
    //do some stuff with age or name
}
```

?

Comment: An addition to Yole's answer, if it memberproperties method is not availabe, just improt this library in your build.gradile file implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.10'

Answer (score 73, accepted):

First of all, the `componentN` properties are available only on data classes, not on every object.

There is no API specifically for iterating over the components, but you can use the [Kotlin reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/member-properties.html) to iterate over properties of any class:

```
class User(val age: Int, val name: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val user = User(25, "Bob")
    for (prop in User::class.memberProperties) {
        println("${prop.name} = ${prop.get(user)}")
    }  
}
```

Comment: One more question. How can I do , or is it possible to do something like: prop.get(this) == prop.get(other)? Thank you.

Comment: You'd need to check and cast each property to a `KProperty1` to invoke getter

Comment: Is this still up to date?  Getting an error that has no attribute memberProperties

Comment: Updated the API link. You need to add the kotlin-reflect to the dependencies to use this method.

Comment: @AdamHughes: add this import line: `import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties`

Comment: i can't import this, maybe older version of kotlin.

Comment: I have made all the imports. However "get" reference cannot be resolved and it returns error for "prop.get"....

Comment: kotlin 1.9.21 got error Type mismatch.
Required:
Nothing
Found:
UserRoomEntity

Answer (score 9):

also, you can use [Properties Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) with built-in delegate 'by map'. it's very useful for some simple stat classes.

```
class DbUsingStat {
  private val map = mutableMapOf(
    "removed" to 0,
    "updated" to 0,
    "skipped" to 0
  )

  var removed by map
  var updated by map
  var skipped by map

  fun asMap() : Map<String, Int> = map.toMap()
}

...
...


val someStatistic = DbUsingStat().apply {
  skipped = 5
  removed = 10
  updated = 1505
}

for((k, v) in someStatistic.asMap())
  println("$k: $v")
```

Comment: Unlucky 'key' should be presented two times, if there're a lot of keys it becomes too big

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a reflection-free solution, here is one.

**Important**: This requires you to be able to modify the `User` data class.

You can write your own iterator function into the data class, like so:

```
data class User(age: Int, name: String) {
    operator fun iterator(): Iterator<Pair<String, Any>> {
        return listOf("age" to age, "name" to name)
    }
}
```

Even though it's a bit of work at first, this allows you to use a for-each style loop like this because Kotlin calls the `iterator()` function in the background to make for-each loops work:

```
val aUserObject: User = User(36, "John Doe")
for ((key, value) in aUserObject) {
    println("$key: $value") // age: 36
                            // name: John Doe
}
```

This keeps your `User` class a data class and doesn't require the use of Reflection.

Comment: what if I have 200 records in Data class?

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin you can do this in the following way, by iterating over the object fields, inside it, is using reflection for this.

```
 private fun prepareData(covidResponse: CovidResponse) {
    for (field in covidResponse.javaClass.declaredFields){
              responseList.add(field as Object)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is an idea...i am not satisfied with it...but nonetheless here it is.

it has some pros and cons:

- pros:

  - type-safe/compile-time checks

    - adding/removing fields to/from the data class causes compiler errors at field-iteration sites
  - no boiler-plate code needed
- cons:

  - won't work if default values are defined for arguments

declaration:

```
data class Memento(
    val testType: TestTypeData,
    val notes: String,
    val examinationTime: MillisSinceEpoch?,
    val administeredBy: String,
    val signature: SignatureViewHolder.SignatureData,
    val signerName: String,
    val signerRole: SignerRole
) : Serializable
```

iterating through all fields:

```
val iterateThroughAllMyFields: Memento = someValue
Memento(
    testType = iterateThroughAllMyFields.testType.also { testType ->
        // do something with testType
    },
    notes = iterateThroughAllMyFields.notes.also { notes ->
        // do something with notes
    },
    examinationTime = iterateThroughAllMyFields.examinationTime.also { examinationTime ->
        // do something with examinationTime
    },
    administeredBy = iterateThroughAllMyFields.administeredBy.also { administeredBy ->
        // do something with administeredBy
    },
    signature = iterateThroughAllMyFields.signature.also { signature ->
        // do something with signature
    },
    signerName = iterateThroughAllMyFields.signerName.also { signerName ->
        // do something with signerName
    },
    signerRole = iterateThroughAllMyFields.signerRole.also { signerRole ->
        // do something with signerRole
    }
)
```