# Python vars() in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This python code

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.one = "python"
    self.two = "is"
    self.three = "fun!"
t=Test()
print(vars(t))
```

prints a collection of fields and their values:
`{'one': 'python', 'two': 'is', 'three': 'fun!'}`
How can I do the same in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Koltin data class you can just print the class

```
 class Test(val one: String, val two: String, val three: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val test = Test("Kotlin", "is", "fun")
    println(test)
}
```

which will produce: `Test(one=Kotlin, two=is, three=fun)`

Kotlin data classes also provide a `componentN()` function. Look [here](https://medium.com/@DarrenAtherton/intro-to-data-classes-in-kotlin-7f956d54365c) for some informations about data classes in Kotlin

For regular classes you can try the approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38688203)