# Is there any efficient way to search throughout a list of objects every field?

Tags: android, kotlin, search

Let's say I have an object

```
data class Person(
   val name: String,
   val surname: String,
   val street: String,
   val postalCode: String,
   val telephoneNumber: String,
)
```

And then I have a list of persons :

```
val personsList = listOf(
  Person(name="John", surname="Hams", street="Gariolg", postalCode="929429", telephoneNumer="+2142422422",),
Person(name="Karl", surname="Hamsteel", street="Gariolg", postalCode="124215", telephoneNumer="+3526522",),
Person(name="Stepf", surname="Hiol", street="Bubmp", postalCode="5342", telephoneNumer="+7574535",),
Person(name="Germa", surname="Foo", street="Hutioa", postalCode="235236", telephoneNumer="+112355",)
)
```

So now if the user types for instance `Hams` it should return John and Karl, because both have the word "Hams" inside the object. What I mean is doesn't matter if the user types postalCode, name, or whatever I'd like to loop throughout the object to check if there's any coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

How i would do it, is create a function inside the data class, say, for example, like this. This will check if any field inside your data class matches with the given string.

In my example i check if whole string matches, but you can change this however you want. You probably want `it.contains(searchString)` inside the any block.

```
fun checkIfStringMatches(searchString: String) : Boolean =
    setOf(this.name, this.surname, this.strees, this.postalCode, this.telephone).any { it == string }
```

Then, you can use this function on your list of persons to filter if any object matches your string search.

```
personList.filter{it.checkIfStringMatches(mySearchString)} // this will return a list with all the objects that match your search criteria
```

The problem is that if you add more fields, you will have to change this function and add it to the `listOf()` block. But i don't know any way to do this automatically without reflection, which is not really recommended to use. If you still want to use it, here is a question on this topic. [Kotlin: Iterate over components of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688111/kotlin-iterate-over-components-of-object)

Comment: `contains(string)` would be a simpler way to write `any { it == string }`. For better performance, an improvement could be to use a lazily-created Set in a property instead of the list, so the `contains` call wouldn't involve iterating. `private val propertyValues by lazy { setOf(name, surname, street, postalCode, telephone) }; fun checkIfStringMatches(string: String) : Boolean = string in propertyValues`

Comment: Good ideea with the set, but i don't think these values should be kep in memory. It probably depends on how often this functionality will be called.
Also, using contains() would not work since he needs a partial match, not a complete match. I used `==` in my example, but i noted that he can also use the other variant for a partial match.

Comment: True, my suggestion wouldn't help for partial matches. I didn't see the OP mention the need for partial matches in the question, but maybe they need that. Whether or not keeping the values in memory is worth it depends on how often this operation is done. The amount of memory taken by the Set would be pretty small, though, since it would be referencing the same String instances that are already referenced by the properties. But of course, there's no point in creating and reusing the set if you need partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work.

```
 personsList.filter { it.surname.startsWith("Hams") }.map {
                Log.d("filter_name", it.name) 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can apply filter method on list and grab the expected output like below :

```
val filtered = personsList.filter { it.toString().contains("Hams", true) }
```

Comment: This approach of transforming the data class to string is not really good, because if the user searches for `telephone` or any string containing the name of any field, it will show all the objects. Say my name is `Naomi`, if i write `Na` it will show all the objects because every one contains the `name` string.

Comment: In this case if you search "Hams", for above question you get only name="John" data. And as per @StuartDTO question, he need John and Karl both data. Which means we need to use string.contains("Hams", true) which return both object.

Comment: He was just making an example, he wants this code to work for any search criteria and any objects. `What I mean is doesn't matter if the user types postalCode, name, or whatever I'd like to loop throughout the object to check if there's any coincidence.`

Comment: Correct @Ionut that's one option I thought of, but wouldn't work because of what you said.