# How to iterate over class properties in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, class, reflection, properties

I have an abstract class ConfigGroup that has the super class ConfigElement.
In ConfigElement a method toJson() is definded. ConfigGroup overrides this method.

Currently toJson() in ConfigGroup looks like this:

```kotlin
override fun toJson(): JsonObject {
        val map: HashMap<String, JsonObject> = HashMap()
        for (child in this::class.declaredMemberProperties) {
            map[child.name] = (child.get(this) as ConfigElement).toJson()
        }
        return JsonObject(map)
    }
```

But when I try to compile it I get `Type mismatch: inferred type is ConfigGroup but Nothing was expected`

I am a bit confused since it is almost the same as the example in [Kotlin: Iterate over components of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688111/kotlin-iterate-over-components-of-object) . The only difference being that I try to get the properties from within the same class and therefore have to use the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the Kotlin compiler isn't smart enough to understand you use exactly the same object for `::class` and for `get()`. In this specific case this is type-safe and could be allowed. However, in more generic case acquiring a `KProperty` from an object and using it to fetch values isn't type-safe and Kotlin intentionally disallows it.

We can fix the problem in the same way as in other cases where the compiler doesn't understand the code is type-safe - by making an unchecked cast:

```kotlin
(child as KProperty1<ConfigGroup, *>).get(this) // or even: KProperty1<Any, *>
```

But wait, why acquiring members of a variable typed as `Animal` and then using it against `animal` instance isn't type-safe? Isn't it guaranteed `animal` has all required members for an animal? Well, not exactly. We may acquire members of a dog and then use it against a cat, because both of them are animals.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    printProperties(Dog(), Cat())
}

fun printProperties(animal1: Animal, animal2: Animal) {
    for (prop in animal1::class.declaredMemberProperties) {
        println("${prop.name}: ${(prop).get(animal2)}") // isn't typesafe, so doesn't compile
    }
}
```

Inside `printProperties`, both `animal1` and `animal2` are of type `Animal`, but their runtime types are different and because of that it is not type-safe to acquire properties from `animal1` and use them against `animal2`.

Kotlin protects against this type of a problem by using variance. If we do `Animal::class` we get a `KClass<Animal>`, so we can use this class for consuming animal objects. But if we do `animal::class`, we get `KClass<out Animal>`, because we can't be sure what is the exact type of `animal`. `KClass<out Animal>` basically says we have a `KClass` for an animal or one of its subtypes and we don't know which one. By default we can't use this `KClass` for consuming animal objects.

In your specific case it is guaranteed we acquired `KClass` from exactly the same runtime type we then try to consume, so this is type-safe and we can safely use an unchecked cast.